# mpi sending message to randomly selected node

Tags: c, mpi, genetic-algorithm

I am trying to implement distributed genetic algorithm (island model) using MPI. All the nodes will repeatedly generate new populations and will exchange best individuals after every k iterations.I wish to make the exchange random such that any process can send a message to any other process. So after every k iterations, each process will send a message to a randomly selected process. However, I am not sure how to implement this with MPI. From this post -[Sending data to randomly selected hosts by using MPI](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7351165/sending-data-to-randomly-selected-hosts-by-using-mpich2) I got the idea that asynchronous communication will be helpful but I am not sure how exactly.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Random communication patterns are difficult to implement in MPI.  MPI is based on all ranks having a deterministic set of communication patterns.

For a point to point solution, each rank will call MPI_Irecv on MPI_ANY_SOURCE.  When the data exchange happens, each rank can call MPI_Send to the specific target rank.  The target rank will need to call MPI_Irecv again to prepare for the next iteration.  When the job is complete, any unused MPI_Irecv calls can be MPI_Cancel'd.

For a collective approach, each rank will call MPI_Alltoall or MPI_Alltoallv (if the amount of data exchanged varies).  Each rank will only populate data to the single rank that is randomly selected to receive data.  This kind of "sparse" data exchange is farily common with MPI_Alltoall.  The collective can be expensive, but it does allow for hard synchronization every k iterations, and avoids the cleanup of MPI_Cancel.

Comment: Thanks! If two senders generate the id of the same receiver and thus both send messages to the same, won't there be loss of message ? Also could you please clarify the point of having two MPI_IRecv's ?

Comment: In the point to point solution, at any given time each rank will have only one MPI_IRecv on MPI_ANY_SOURCE outstanding.  If a message is matched, then a new MPI_Irecv should be posted to allow for the "next" random message to be received.  I did not consider the case where "i" ranks all randomly pick the same target rank.  In that case, the MPI_Alltoall solution would be preferable.  The difficulty in the point-to-point case is that there would need to be a separate "all clear" message or collective call to allow all the ranks to know it is time to proceed with the next set of iterations.

Comment: An excellent answer. Nevertheless, I think it would be interesting to implement an asynchronous solution. I once did that for my diploma thesis and it was significantly faster than the synchronized algorithm and with equal quality. I used a master slave approach however and parallelized only the evaluation. The master maintained a list of working and idle slaves to decide where to send solutions.